# Using an AWS service with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku

We currently have a Rails server running on Heroku and would like to add Elasticsearch. This would normally be very easy to set up but the problem is that it would be $150/ month to handle our 5 million+ rows of data (definitely over budget).

On AWS they have an Elasticsearch service that's a lot cheaper but our concern is that using AWS Elasticsearch with Heroku Rails could lead to latency issues. Is it possible to use an AWS service with Heroku and have them be in the same server farm? (I believe Heroku uses AWS anyways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions#data-center-locations), Heroku US uses Amazon region `us-east-1`, Amazon's Virginia region. Heroku EU uses Amazon region `eu-west-1`, Amazon's Ireland region. You need to setup your ElasticSearch service on AWS in the same region as your Heroku servers in order to ensure low latency.

You can read more about AWS regions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html).

Comment: That's great! Any ideas on how to set up security?

Comment: You won't have any control of the IP addresses or AWS security groups your Heroku application is using, so you will have to rely on passwords and possibly HTTPS to secure communication. I'm not familiar with the ElasticSearch service but you should be able to use an AWS internal IP/hostname for the service such that all communication stays within the AWS network instead of going over the internet. You will want to do that anyway in order to reduce latency.